# How to identify the input in which the key was pressed in JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I use the following jQuery code to process keys which are pressed in various input tags:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("input").keydown(function (e) {processKeys(e);});
    ...
```

It works great...

In a separate Javascript file I have a function which receives the event call:

```
function processKeys(e) {
    key=e.which;
    if (key==27) {
        $("#searchCDB").hide();
    }

}
```

So, is there a way for me to identify the `<input>` tag which caused the event  at the event layer...  What I mean is here, in some way like:

```
$("input").keydown(function (e) {processKeys($("#this"),e);});
```

I know my attempt is absurd, but any suggestion that works will be appreciated.

DK

Comment: Just pass `this` (or `$(this)`). Or, use `e.target`. Your question isn't absurd, I just think you're overthinking it

Comment: You can simplify `.keydown(function (e) {processKeys(e);});` to `.keydown(processKeys);`. And btw, the answer to your question is provided in the official jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Comment: @FelixKling That definitely makes most sense!

Comment: You can read it from the event, `e.target` or `e.currentTarget`

Comment: @lan I get the following result `[object HTMLInputElement]` from your `e.target` recommendation

Comment: @DKean Yes, that's expected. You'd get the same thing if you looked at `this` (or the argument `this` is passed as)

Comment: @lan The real solution is this:  `tID=e.currentTarget.attributes.id` not just e.currentTarget.  Nevertheless, you led me to the answer.   So, thank you.  I used FireBug's 'Watch' feature to figure it out... in case anyone wants to know.  And I will give the solution with my answer to my own question.  I hope that no one is offended, because you all helped.

Comment: @FelixKling While there seems to be wisdom in your answer, I do not know how you are passing the event unless you do it this way: `.keydown(processKeys(e));`  Sorry for the delayed reply, I was testing the other people's suggestions...

Comment: You are not passing the event. The function you pass the callback to passes the event. Maybe this simple example helps you to understand: Passing an anonymous function: `.keydown(function(e) {...});` or defining the function beforehand `var foo = function(e) {...}; element.keydown(foo);` makes no difference. Do you see that both function both define the `e` parameter? All that `.keydown` gets is a function reference, no matter *how* it was created. It later calls it with `callback(event)` (or something similar).

Comment: Oh, I understand!  But I have the function defined in code, not stored in a variable as you suggest:  `var foo = function(e) {...};`  I guess that I could insert the `var foo = function(e)`.  And yes, that is a very good idea.  But I found how to extract the ID with `tID=e.currentTarget.attributes.id`.  Do you see a problem with that?  But I will gladly keep your idea in mind for future use, though.  This is the first time I grasped that way of doing things.  Wow!  Passing a function as a parameter...Great!  Almost as good as VFP '&var'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `this` to your `processKeys` function:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("input").keydown(function (e) {
        processKeys(e, this);
    });
});

function processKeys(e, obj) {
    console.log(obj.id); //logs ID of keypressed input
    key=e.which;
    if (key==27) {
        $("#searchCDB").hide();
    }

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uE7ZD/

Comment: Yes it does.  But I tried using that method before and it did not.  So, thank you for a good solution.  I have to give you that one!  Thank you!  Good show...